# When I create an arrow in Sketch and enlarge it, the tail bursts out of the arrow

Tags: logo, sketch-app

I've been creating an arrow in Sketch and whenever I adjust the Size property of the border, it decides to burst out the side of the `<` part of the arrow. Is there anyway to fix this, or am I messing with the wrong value?

[image]

Comment: Anyone? .....  :(

Comment: We have quite small group of people here who use / know how Gimp or Inkscape work and questions regarding those programs have pretty hard time getting answered (in my opinion). I wouldn't keep my hopes very high for questions regarding Sketch :/

Comment: @Joonas I thought Sketch was an Autodesk product?  How do you get Gimp and Inkscape from that?  To OP how are you creating the symbol?  Are you creating it from within the program or are you making it from scratch?

Comment: @Matt_2.0 The point is that those two are are way older than Sketch, not to mention free and multiplatform but even so, questions about them are having hard time getting answers here. --  Sketch is not Sketchbook. It's this http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

Comment: @joonas your point is valid (Sketch is not widely used), that said, I've seen plenty of Inkscape and Gimp answers here.

Comment: @Matt_2.0 it's not autodesk: http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've probably solved this by now, but for the sake of others who hope to make Sketch their Adobe killer (like me) here's the real answer.

## Sketch's arrow shape tool sucks.

You're problem lies in the stroke end style. Take a look at these arrows and their corresponding stroke end settings.

1. This one is sucky.
   [image]
2. This one is less so.
   [image]

I've also noticed a serious screen drawing issue with the arrow shape but not with other shape objects. I think there's just a bug with the poor thing.

Sketch is a young app. These things are bound to plague us hopeful early users. Fortunately, Bohemian just brought on [two new employees](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/about/blog/growing-by-two/) to keep things moving ahead. Let's all hope for something great in [Sketch 3.0](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/beta/)!

Comment: Is Sketch your Adobe killer? I was looking at that (and Xara, and Corel, and FOSS...) was was curious.

Comment: Nice. @Brendan Sketch users hope that someday it will be.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not there yet. It has a few shortcomings that make it unusable for my normal projects (very complex pages/web apps). But it does have some amazing workflow improvements over Illustrator (my favored tool) that prove Bohemian is stepping out of the norm to do something bigger and better. I'll keep experimenting and waiting anxiously for v3.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me if the arrow is using a tool to {magically} tack on an arrow to a line, or if it is a composite vector.

If it is a composite, just move the left anchor rightwards. This may cause a gap at smaller border sizes. Alternatively, merge the shapes before applying the border.

If it is a {magic} shape, enlarge the shape and use a color fill, don't alter the border size.

Note that when enlarging a vector, the software must make an uninformed decision about how to handle attributes like borders. Some scale them, some leave them alone, some let you pick, some default to the one you wouldn't choose. For this reason, it is sometimes a good idea to not rely on these effects to define the shape of items which may be scaled in applications which you have no control over. (such as my grandmother's web browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use a dashed arrow, you'll probably need to combine a simple, dashed line to make the body of the arrow with an arrow shape to make for the point of the arrow (using the first "end" option as explained by Plainclothes). Otherwise expect ugly shapes.